# Python: TypeError: expected bytes, dict found (Try to do a nested metadata)

Tags: python, metadata, pyarrow

I want to make nested metadata as below:

```
schema = pa.schema([pa.field('Id', pa.string(), metadata={"pg_dtype": {"dtype": "int[36]", "pkey": "1"}}), 
                    pa.field('Name', pa.string(), metadata={"pg_dtype": {"dtype": "varchar[20]", "pkey": "1"}})])
```

but getting this error

```
TypeError: expected bytes, dict found
```

I refer to this nested dict example to make nested metadata

```
people = {'type': {'name': 'John', 'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male'},
          'type': {'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female'}}
```

Comment: According to the [official examples](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Schema.html#pyarrow.Schema.metadata) it looks like `metadata` should be its own argument, outside of the array containing `pa.field()`. So, you have `schema = pa.schema([..., metadata={"pg_dtype": {"dtype": "int[36]", "pkey": "1"}})])` but I think it should be like `schema = pa.schema([...], metadata={"pg_dtype": {"dtype": "int[36]", "pkey": "1"}})`

Comment: @RandomDavis [`pa.field`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.field.html) also has a `metadata` argument

Comment: yeah, trying to do nested metadata for each field

Comment: There isn't nested metadata, it's key-value only: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/dd84c0f68c6f898e3a02bb0623500e3f165f80d4/format/Schema.fbs#L480-L481

Answer (score 1):

`metadata` should be a `dict` with keys and values as `str` (or `bytes`). You can't have a nested dict in it. You'd have to dump the nested dict (`pg_dtypes`) as a json string:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import json

schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('Id', pa.string(), metadata={"pg_dtype": json.dumps({"dtype": "int[36]", "pkey": "1"})}), 
    pa.field('Name', pa.string(), metadata={"pg_type": json.dumps({"dtype": "varchar[20]", "pkey": "1"})})
])

schema.field('Name').metadata
>>> {b'pg_type': b'{"dtype": "varchar[20]", "pkey": "1"}'}
```

This works but I'm not sure it's the right format of pg to pick it up.